# Nullable fields are created when customizing IdentityUser class in asp.net Identity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am trying to customize IdentityUser class in asp.net identity.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        IsBlocked = false;
    }

    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is: when using code first migrations, the additional field is created nullable.
The same if I drop database and recreate it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]            NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [UserName]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PasswordHash]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [IsConfirmed]   BIT            NOT NULL,
    [IsBlocked]     BIT            NULL,
    [Discriminator] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

How can I fix this?

I have boolean fields in other classes on the same DbContext, and they are all created not null (as they should).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original answer, below, assumed you had an abstract base class, and therefore were using TPC, or possibly TPT if you specified the `[Table]` attribute on the concrete class, rather than [TPH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738443%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

However, if you are using a non-abstract base class and do not specify a `[Table]` on your `ApplicationUser`, and therefore your `ApplicationUser` and `IdentityUser` map to a single table, then you are using the TPH scenario. In this scenario any fields from a subclass will be nullable in your single table. The only way to change this is to switch to TPC or TPT.

**Original answer**

Put the [`[Required]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) attribute on your property:

```cs
[Required]
public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }
```

Your migration should then make it a `NON NULL` column.

However, if you already have data in your table this will cause issues as it won't know what default value to create. In this case I edit the migration to first make it a `NULL` column, then run a [`Sql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) command to set the values I want, and then [`AlterColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.altercolumn%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) make it a `NON NULL` column

```cs
AddColumn("dbo.MyTable", "MyColumn", c => c.Boolean());
Sql("UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = 1");
AlterColumn("dbo.MyTable", "MyColumn", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
```

Comment: I have tried to, but nothing changed. Once more: in other entities on the same DbContext all properties of non-nullable types (including bool) produce non-nullable fields in the database. The problem is only with this one.

Comment: Is it possible you are using TPH? If so then you probably can't make that particular field non null.